# NestJs: Dynamically Create Instances of Class

Tags: dependency-injection, factory, nestjs

Instead of Singletons, I want to create dynamically class instances in NestJs.

I found two ways:

#### 1) Directly create the class (ChripSensor is then not @Injectable)

```
import { ChirpSensor } from './chirp-sensor/chirp-sensor';

@Injectable()
export class SensorsService {
  registeredSensors: any;
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('Sensor') private readonly sensorModel: Model<ISensor>,
    private i2cService: I2cService) {
       const sensors = this.i2cService.getSensors();
       sensors.forEach((sensor) => {this.registeredSensors[sensor._id] = new ChirpSensor({name: sensor.name})});

    }
```

I'm wondering if that is consistent with the DI way of nest.js

#### 2) The second solution would be via a [factory](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers), but here I don't know how to pass the options.

```
export const chirpFactory = {
  provide: 'CHIRP_SENSOR',
  useFactory: (options) => {
    console.log('USING FACTORY CHIRP, options', options)
    if (process.env.SIMULATION === 'true') {
      return new ChirpSensorMock(options);
    }
    else {
      return new ChirpSensor(options);
    }
  }
};
```

Not quite sure how to continue here/ inject the factory properly as the examples create the object in the constructor without options?

### Question:

What is the `NestJs` way to create those class instances?

## Edit - for B12Toastr

#### Module - get the Mock or Original on Compile time

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: 'CHIRP_SENSOR',
    useValue: process.env.SIMULATION === 'true'
      ? ChirpSensorMock
      : ChirpSensor
  },
],
```

#### Sensor Service

```
@Injectable()
export class SensorsService {
  registeredSensors: any;
  constructor(
    @Inject('CHIRP_SENSOR') private ChirpSensorClass: any, // any works but ChirpSensorMock | ChirpSensor not
    private i2cService: I2cService
   ) {
    const sensors = this.i2cService.getSensors();
    sensors.forEach((sensor) => {this.registeredSensors[sensor._id] = new ChirpSensorClass({name: sensor.name})});

  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass options to your factory via DI via [useValue](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#value-providers-usevalue) or [useClass](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#class-providers-useclass)

```js
providers: [
  {
    provide: MyOptions,
    useValue: options
  },
  {
    provide: 'CHIRP_SENSOR',
    useFactory: (options: MyOptions) => {
      console.log('USING FACTORY CHIRP, options', options);
      if (process.env.SIMULATION === 'true') {
        return new ChirpSensorMock(options);
      } else {
        return new ChirpSensor(options);
      }
    },
  },
],
```

Alternatively, you could also avoid using a factory altogether and make the decision which class to use at compile time via:

```js
providers: [
  {
    provide: MyOptions,
    useValue: options
  },
  {
    provide: 'CHIRP_SENSOR',
    useValue: process.env.SIMULATION === 'true'
      ? ChirpSensorMock
      : ChirpSensor
  },
],
```

or simply:

```js
providers: [
  {
    provide: MyOptions,
    useValue: options
  },
  {
    process.env.SIMULATION === 'true' ? ChirpSensorMock : ChirpSensor
  },
],
```

In case you are not using a factory as described above, you would then inject the options in your `ChirpSensor` (or the Mocked Sensor)` using typical constructor-based dependency injection:

```js
@Injectable()
export class ChripSensor {
  constructor(@inject(MyOptions) private options: MyOptions) {
  }

  // ...
}
```

Depending on whether your options are wrapped in a class or a simple object you would either use `useValue` or `useClass`. With `useClass` you have to write less code and do not have to use the `@Inject` decorator since the class itself is used as DI token. However, it seems if `MyOptions` is a class, you do not need to use `@Inject` in any case to inject the dependency because NestJS uses the class as DI token, regardless whether you used `useValue` or `useClass` to provide the dependency...

Comment: In the second case:
`process.env.SIMULATION === 'true' ? ChirpSensorMock : ChirpSensor` if I use this via DI in my service, how would I pass the options? Or would I import the factory and then call the factory outside of the constructor? I mean could you add how to use the solution in the `SensorsService `.

Comment: I mean options is still passed to either ChirpSensorMock or ChirpSensor and maybe retrieved through another service, as shown in the 1st example.

Comment: And it would be probably `useClass`, I guess.

Comment: Hi @AndiGiga, yes correct you would use DI for passing the options as in the 1st example, I added this to the code for clarification and further elaborated on this at the bottom of my answer. Depending on if you wrapped your options in a class or not, you would either provide the options as class-based service (using `useClass`) or a simple object or other type (`useValue`).

Comment: I made an edit above. As the options are dynamic and retrieved from i2cService I made an example above with your solution. I think it works now but only with the `any`type. Maybe you got any recommendation on how to deal with the type then.  I get `This expression is not constructable.
  Type 'ChirpSensorMock' has no construct signatures.`

Comment: first you are using PascalCase for the instance you are injecting in your constructor which may cover up the import `ChirpSensorClass`, for good style and to avoid import problems it should be `chirpSensorClass: any` or better `chirpSensorClass: ChirpSensorClass`, second, try `{ provide: ChirpSensor, useClass: process.env.SIMULATION === 'true' ? ChirpSensorMock : ChirpSensor },` (note the useClass and the ChirpSensor being the DI token) and then in your SensorsService use: `constructor(private chirpSensor: ChirpSensor`. Hope it helps, good luck.

Comment: That's exactly what I need to do and I opted for a DynamicModule where I pass the `useClass` from outside, based on `process.env.MOCKS_ENABLED`.
I hoped there was a cleaner way like I do in Angular projects, but it appears there isn't.
It's ugly because you need to have a consistent imported module, whereas in Angular I just override stuff without touching anything. I was lucky because I'm working with custom modules...but what if I was using libs? 

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but the original question was: "How to create a series of `@Injectable` `ChirpSensorClass` instances with different options(`{name: sensor.name}`) iterating over some array? And then address them somehow to `@Inject` in other places.
Is it possible?
As I understand in your solution `useFactory` functions will be called once for single `MyOptions` instance. Isn't it?